# Draw rectangle around Textbox inside a Groupbox

Tags: vb.net, graphics, drawrectangle

I want to add a custom border around a `TextBox` control which is in a `GroupBox`.
Since I'm new to this Graphic stuff I'm having a hard time figuring out the problem.

This is the code i'm using:

```
Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint

    Dim _g As Graphics = Me.GroupBox1.CreateGraphics
    Dim pen As New Pen(Color.Red, 2.0)
    _g.DrawRectangle(pen, New Rectangle(TextBox1.Location, TextBox1.Size))
    pen.Dispose()

End Sub
```

This form is a secondary form that shows when I click on a button from the Main form. The Red Border appears for a second when the form loads and then disappears.

Comment: You need to handle the groupbox paint event. Not the form.

Comment: Oops! Didn't thought about that. Thanks it worked. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to handle the GroupBox paint event, not the form.

```
Private Sub HandleGroupBox1Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles GroupBox1.Paint
    Using p As New Pen(Color.Red, 2.0)
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(p, Me.TextBox1.bound)
    End Using
End Sub
```