# Can't draw rectangle around textbox in Groupbox, using Visual Basic 2010.-

Tags: vb.net

I have two textbox controls in a vb form.- I can draw rectangles about the two textbox if they aren't in a groupbox.- Only when the textbox got the focus the rectangle is drawed.- The code works, but somehow, when i put the textbox in a groupbox the rectangles aren't drawed.-

[the rectangle only is drawed when textbox is focused](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15476910/2014_08_26_08_43_27_Form1.png)

This is the code that i have been using.-

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim curControl As TextBox
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub
Private Sub Form1_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PaintEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Paint
    If Not curControl Is Nothing Then
        If curControl.Name = "TextBox1" Then
            Dim g As Graphics = e.Graphics
            Dim pen As New Pen(Color.Lime, 2.0)
            g.DrawRectangle(pen, New Rectangle(TextBox1.Location, TextBox1.Size))
            pen.Dispose()
        End If
    End If
    If Not curControl Is Nothing Then
        If curControl.Name = "TextBox2" Then
            Dim g As Graphics = e.Graphics
            Dim pen As New Pen(Color.Red, 2.0)
            g.DrawRectangle(pen, New Rectangle(TextBox2.Location, TextBox2.Size))
            pen.Dispose()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox_Enter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Enter, TextBox2.Enter
    curControl = DirectCast(sender, TextBox)
    Me.Invalidate()
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox_Leave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Leave, TextBox2.Leave
    curControl = Nothing
    Me.Invalidate()
End Sub
```

Comment: you are drawing on the form not on the groupbox

Comment: I've tried drawing in the groupbox using
Private Sub groupbox1_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PaintEventArgs) Handles groupbox1.Paint ... but doesn't works (excuse my english, it ain't my native tongue)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Draw rectangle around Textbox inside a Groupbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24584327/draw-rectangle-around-textbox-inside-a-groupbox)

Comment: Why doesn't it work? Does it give an error, or does it not show up? You might want to make sure it's visible and that it's brought to the front.

Comment: Does not show up.- The textbox are visibles and brought to the front.-